# Merging specific lines in a CSV file if specific trend is found out

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have been stuck with creating the script for below mentioned scenario:
I have a file a.csv with content as

```
123,fsfs,4124124,412412
1314,fasfwe,42145,rwr
1234,fwtrwqt,twt
wqrfsdgaseg
12424,23532,fafwe,gewgt
14214,wet,wertwtw,wet
```

What happens is, due to some application, the CSV content of one line gets printed on the second line.

My task is to find such occurrence and merge the such lines in a new file.
so new files will contains only required CSV records I tried few things using sed, but couldn't succeed.

Comment: you realize that Stackoverflow is about helping people with programming problems, and NOT a free coding service? In any case, you need to show us, at least!, what the output from your sample input should be. Your verbal description is ambiguous. Good luck.

Comment: Apologies buddy, but this was the first time I had to ask specific question here as was time bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All previous answers seem great, but I wanted to add a `sed` answer as well because `sed` is awesome! (And `sed` was added as a tag so we were missing a `sed` answer.)

This answer should work on multiple lines, provided that the cut always happen on a separator and that that separator is omitted (see input example for these assumptions).

```
sed ':l;/\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*/!{;N;s/\n/,/g;bl;}' <file_in >file_out
```

What it does is :

- defines a label (`:l`)
- tests if there are four fields (`/\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*/`)
- If there isn't (`!`), execute the block (`{;N;s/\n/,/g;bl;}`)

The block :

- reads the next line into the buffer (`N`)
- replaces the newline with the separator (`s/\n/,/g`)
- loops by branching to our `:l`label (`bl`)

Proof :

```
$ sed ':l;/\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*/!{;N;s/\n/,/g;bl;}' <<EOF
> 123,fsfs,4124124,412412
> 1314,fasfwe,42145,rwr
> 1234,fwtrwqt,twt
> wqrfsdgaseg
> 12424,23532,fafwe,gewgt
> 14214,wet,wertwtw,wet
> EOF
123,fsfs,4124124,412412
1314,fasfwe,42145,rwr
1234,fwtrwqt,twt,wqrfsdgaseg
12424,23532,fafwe,gewgt
14214,wet,wertwtw,wet
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will see if this can be implemented for my requirements as this works for my test data

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, '!length $4 && length $3 {printf "%s,", $0;next}1' file 
123,fsfs,4124124,412412
1314,fasfwe,42145,rwr
1234,fwtrwqt,twt,wqrfsdgaseg
12424,23532,fafwe,gewgt
14214,wet,wertwtw,wet
```

Comment: Thanks Sputnick. I will use your awk solution for my script. I managed to get the thing done by using xarg and awk, but would be happy to implement all the solutions posted by all here and see, which is the best one